# Getting error when i try to import bluetooth on python2.7

Tags: python, bluetooth, pybluez

I got python2.7 installed on a raspeberry pi 4 with a script which use the bluethooth library(pybluez) but the script was crashing when importing the library.
Si i simply try to import the bluetooth library on a python2.7 shell and i have the same error "AttributeEror: attribute '**doc**' of 'instancemethod' objects is not writable"

I can't switch to python3 and i don't understand why it's not working so if someone got an issue to this i would be grateful :)

code:

```
Import bluetooth

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/__init__.py", line 282,
in <module>
"""
AtributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'instancemethod' objects is not writable
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what code you are using. `https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/bluetooth/__init__.py` doesn't even *have* a line 282.

Comment: Yes sorry,  i am just trying to import the library "bluetooth" that i run in a python shell and then i got the message starting from "Traceback" .

Comment: `bluetooth` is not in the standard library, so you must have installed the code from somewhere. We can't help you if we don't know what code that is.

Comment: i did " sudo apt-get install python-bluez"  to install the library

Comment: Maybe i got the wrong version i don't know .. there is the code("__init__") on my github --> https://github.com/mathieu-gouleau/prd

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue and fixxed it by using [this](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/bluetooth/__init__.py) **init**.py

somewhere near line 8 it says "version" and the "old" init.py i used was 0.23 the one working is 0.22.
Btw i used pip install to get the 0.23.

Answer (score 0):

Another means to fix...
Installed bluez with the following:
sudo apt-get install bluetooth
sudo apt-get install bluez libbluetooth-dev
sudo python -m pip install pybluez

and got this error.
fixed it by using python3 and installing pybluez with
sudo python3 -m pip install pybluez

btw the install is based on:https://blog.adafruit.com/2020/04/17/starting-with-raspberry-pi-bluetooth-python-python-bluetooth-raspberrypi-piday-raspberry_pi/